# Advice needed for connecting multiple arduinos as slave to raspberry pi

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, usb, i2c, serial-communication

I have a project in hand where I need to connect 5 or more arduinos as slaves to Raspberry Pi. Load Cells, Reed Switch, Solenoid lock will be connected to each of the arduino. The arduinos need to send the weight readings when a communication is started by the raspberry pi(master). Only a single arduino will be activated at a time. The arduinos will be placed at a maximum of 6ft distance from the raspberry pi. I need advice regarding how to make this connection. I read that I2C cannot be used for long distances so I am unsure if 6 ft is a long distance for I2C. Next, I am trying to see if a USB would work for my case but the issue is the Pi has only 4 USB slots. So can I use a external USB hub with an external power supply and connected each of the arduinos to the USB hub and provide individual power supply to the arduinos? Will this arrangement work or should I be looking at any other protocol apart from I2C and USB?? Any advice on this will be much appreciated. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Arduino (Nano, Uno, Mega etc.) can communicate via SPI, I2C or UART.

- Long story short, SPI is not suitable for your application. It is used for fast data transfer over short distances (usually milimeters or centimeters), so mainly for communication between chips mounted on the same PCB or PCBs close together (e.g. display shields).
- Using I2C is perfectly fine (let's say up to 10 meters) and in your case it is a way to go. The maximum possible length depends on baud rate, for 10 meters a 9600 baud rate would be OK. The big advantage is that you need only 2 wires to connect all Arduinos, the disadvantage is that only one device can transfer data at the time – in your case, that does not matter.
- UART is used for communication with many external modules (GSM, GPS, HMI, ...) and also in combination with USB-TTL chip for communication via USB (virtual COM port). In your case, you can use UART e.g. in combination with external UART-RS485 converter module, but there is no need since you can use I2C.

Comment: Thanks for the advice JSC. I will look into I2C as suggested.